# strong and independent extra explanatory variable doesn't improve linear regression

Tags: regression, feature-selection, prediction, predictor

So I already have a linear regression on 3 predictors $Y = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$. Now I have an extra predictor $X_4$.

Before I put in $X_4$, the original predictor using $\hat{Y} = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$ has correlation of about **6%** with the real $Y$ I am trying to predict. But After I put in $X_4$ and have a new regressional predictor $\hat{Y'} = X_1 + X_2 + X_3 + X_4 $, $\hat{Y'}$ makes virtually no improvement over original regression $\hat{Y}$.

$X_4$ is reasonably independent of $\hat{Y} = X_1 + X_2 + X_3$. It has only about **3%** of correlation to original estimation $\hat{Y}$. $X_4$ is also reasonably strong predictor -- about **1.5%** correlated to real $Y$ I am trying to predict.

My question is why does $X_4$ makes no improvement, even though it's quite strong and quite independent of the original predictors? Or is it not strong and independent enough? **Or more generally, is there a mathematical formula or empirical formula could tell whether an extra variable should improve the regression?**

I have used multiple R packages, like rlm, lmrob, etc, doesn't make any difference to my experiment

Comment: All of the equations are wrong. Try to to correct them first.

Comment: None of the facts you quote are relevant to your question: what matters is the correlation between $X_4$ and the *residuals* in the regression $Y\sim X_1+X_2+X_3;$ namely, $Y-\hat Y.$  Please search our site for [added variable plot](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=added+variable+plot+score%3A2)